# After copying app.config file a folder outside the project, when trying to read settings return null

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I copy app.config file at runtime to a path mentoined in "Start External Program Folder" under Debug section of my project properties. I have set "Copy to Output Directory=Copy always".
When i try to read this app.config file from new location using below code, i get null.

```
string targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "NewFolder");
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, "App.config");
string sourceFile = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\App.config";

if (!File.Exists(destFile))
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
}


Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(destFile);
NameValueCollection sAll = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

Comment: What is `null`? `myConfig` or `sAll`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, sALL is null

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading `AppSettings` from `myConfig`?

Comment: What exactly "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" is doing?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), "Gets the AppSettingsSection data for the current application's default configuration.". `OpenExeConfiguration` does not load those values into the default configuration it seems

Comment: If i do ConfigurationManager.AppSettings then which app.config file it will refer to? Will it return appsettings information from the app.config from new location?

Comment: It will refer to the default one, which doesn't exist. You need to use `myConfig.AppSettings`

Comment: myConfig.Appsettings.Settings count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Please refer below code.

```
                ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = appconfigDestFile;
                Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```